# Jira, create a custom button and do an action against it

Tags: groovy, workflow, jira

this is my first question here, i hope i convey it well for you to understand,
i want a button to display on issue details page in Jira.
when clicked it would check if (Report == Assignee) and set 'Assignee' to 'NULL' or clear that field.

If you have any other suggestions please let me know how can i implement this better.

Answer (score 1):

You have not described what you want the button to do clearly, but creating a new web item (issue operation) is usually done with a plugin: https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Web+Item+Plugin+Module

Comment: can i call a groovy script using web item?

Answer (score 1):

In each workflow step where this is desired, you can create a transition *Clear Assignee* with:

- *condition* which checks that *Reporter* and *Assignee* field are equal (e.g. from the [JIRA Workflow Enhancer](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.tng.jira.plugins.workflowenhancer) plugin)
- *post function* **Update Issue Field** (from the [JIRA Suite Utilities](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.googlecode.jira-suite-utilities) plugin) or similar which sets the value to nothing